# Swift .uppercaseString or .lowercaseString property replacement

Tags: swift

Since Strings in Swift no longer have the .uppercaseString or .lowercaseString properties available, how would i go about performing that function?

If I have for example:

```
var sillyString = "This is a string!"
let yellyString = sillyString.uppercaseString
let silentString = sillyString.lowercaseString
```

I would like to take sillyString and mutate it into either uppercase or lowercase. How would i go about doing that now?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

### Xcode 6.0 / Swift 1.0

`String` is bridged seamlessly to `NSString`, so it **does** have `uppercaseString` and `lowercaseString` properties *as long as you `import Foundation`* (or really almost any framework since they'll usually `import Foundation` internally. From the [Strings and Characters section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_418) of the Swift Programming Guide:

> Swift’s String type is bridged seamlessly to Foundation’s NSString
>   class. If you are working with the Foundation framework in Cocoa or
>   Cocoa Touch, the entire NSString API is available to call on any
>   String value you create, in addition to the String features described
>   in this chapter. You can also use a String value with any API that
>   requires an NSString instance.

---

### Xcode 6.1 / Swift 1.1

As @newacct pointed out, in Xcode 6.1 / Swift 1.1, `uppercaseString` and `lowercaseString` **are** in Swift's `String` class so you don't need to use the ones defined in `NSString`. However, it's implemented as an extension to the `String` class in the `Foundation` framework so the solution is still the same: `import Foundation`

In a playground:

```
import Foundation

var sillyString = "This is a string!" // --> This is a string!
let yellyString = sillyString.uppercaseString // --> THIS IS A STRING!
let silentString = sillyString.lowercaseString // --> this is a string!
```

---

### Swift 3.0

In a playground:

```
import Foundation

var sillyString = "This is a string!" // --> This is a string!
let yellyString = sillyString.uppercased() // --> THIS IS A STRING!
let silentString = sillyString.lowercased() // --> this is a string!
```

Comment: `uppercaseString` and `lowercaseString` are defined as properties on `String` in Foundation. `NSString` is not involved.

Comment: @newacct So they are, thanks for pointing that out. It looks like the change happened between Xcode 6.0 / Swift 1.0 and Xcode 6.1 / Swift 1.1.

Answer (score 82):

## Swift 4 & 5

### TL;DR

The new names in Swift 3 use the `-ed` postfix to indicate that `uppercased()` and `lowercased()` return a copy rather than a modified original:

```
import Foundation

let title = "Castration: The Advantages and the Disadvantages" // Don't `var` unless you have to!
title.uppercased() // "CASTRATION: THE ADVANTAGES AND THE DISADVANTAGES"
title.lowercased() // "castration: the advantages and the disadvantages"
title.capitalized  // "Castration: The Advantages And The Disadvantages"
```

### Inconsistencies: .method() vs .property

Note the odd discrepancy where uppercased() and lowercased() are functions, while capitalized is a property. This seems like an oversight, in which case hopefully someone comfortable with the swift evolution process will make a correction before 3.0 leaves beta.

If happen to know you're working with NSString, there *is* a property available for all three:

```
NSString(string: "abcd").uppercased
NSString(string: "ABCD").lowercased
NSString(string: "abCd").capitalized
```

### Language is Hard

The methods above hide a whole string of method delegations to NSString and CFString with a default Locale of nil. This works most of the time. At least, it does in English. The fact is, I don't really understand the rest of what I'm about to paste from my playground.

```
let turkishI = "\u{0130} is not I"                  // "İ is not I"
turkishI.uppercased()                               // "İ IS NOT I"
turkishI.uppercased(with: Locale(identifier: "en")) // "İ IS NOT I"
turkishI.uppercased(with: Locale(identifier: "tr")) // "İ İS NOT I"
turkishI.lowercased()                               // "i̇ is not i"
turkishI.capitalized                                // "İ Is Not I"
turkishI.lowercased(with: Locale(identifier: "en")) // "i̇ is not i"
turkishI.lowercased(with: Locale(identifier: "tr")) // "i is not ı"
```

### Swift 3

The Locale initializer has a slightly longer parameter name in Swift 3…

```
turkishI.uppercased(with: Locale(localeIdentifier: "en"))
```

### Light Humor

```
"✈️".uppercased()  //  (Swift 4)
"✈️".uppercased()  //  (Swift 5)
```

Comment: the discrepancy regarding uppercased() / lowercased() being functions and capitalized being a property is still present in Swift 5. Odd.

Answer (score 13):

The `uppercaseString` and `lowercaseString` properties on `String` are not in the Swift standard library anymore. Instead, `Foundation` provides them now. So you have to

```
import Foundation
```

to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the function from Apple Docs for Xcode8/Swift3:

> ```
> /// Returns a lowercase version of the string.
> ///
> /// Here's an example of transforming a string to all lowercase letters.
> ///
> ///     let cafe = "Café "
> ///     print(cafe.lowercased())
> ///     // Prints "café "
> ///
> /// - Returns: A lowercase copy of the string.
> ///
> /// - Complexity: O(*n*)
> public func lowercased() -> String
> ```

Answer (score 0):

### SwiftUI Solution

The Solution in SwiftUI to uppercase a string

```
Text("Hello World!".uppercased())
```

The output would be: "HELLO WORLD!"

---

To lowercase the string just use this

```
Text("Hello World!".lowercased())
```

The output would be: "hello world!"