# How can I set http in searchBar case insensitive?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uisearchbar, case-insensitive

There is a `searchBar` on top of a `webView`so users can put in new internet addresses. I found when `http` changed to `Http` it doesn't work any more. How can I set `case insensitive` for web address? Thanks!

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    if searchBar.text != nil {

        let address = searchBar.text!

        if address.containsString("http://") || address.containsString("https://") {

        let str = address

        if let newUrl = NSURL(string: str) {

          let newRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: newUrl)

          myWebView.loadRequest(newRequest)

          }

        } else {

            let str = "http://" + String(address)

            if let newUrl = NSURL(string: str) {

                let newRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: newUrl)

                myWebView.loadRequest(newRequest)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing this:

[Here is a link to another stack overflow talking about uppercase and lowercase strings.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245645/swift-uppercasestring-or-lowercasestring-property-replacement)

You should be able to put the whole string to lowercase by doing:

```
let address = searBar.text!.lowercaseString
```

That should convert the address string to all lowercase.
You might also want to consider changing the capitalization for the search bar box to be disabled.

Another solution might be to check if address.contains("Http://")

Best,
Joe

Comment: Great!  Happy to help!